# Why is my output 11 characters long when it should be 100?

Tags: loops, kotlin, project

I am currently working on a Hyperskill project, and the project description is as follows:

"The password is hard to crack if it contains at least A uppercase letters, at least B lowercase letters, at least C digits, and includes exactly N symbols. Also, a password cannot contain two or more same characters coming one after another. For a given numbers A, B, C, N you should output a password that matches these requirements.

It is guaranteed A, B, C, and N are non-negative integers and A + B + C <= N. Keep in mind, that any parameter can be equal to zero. It means that it's ok if the password doesn't contain symbols of such type.

Sample Input: 3 4 1 8

Sample Output: PaSsw0rD"

Here is my code:

```
while (total != 0) {
    choice = (1..3).random()
    if (choice == 1 && letterA != 0) {
        password += ('A'..'Z').random()
        letterA -= 1
        total -= 1
    } else if (choice == 2 && letterB != 0) {
        password += ('a'..'z').random()
        letterB -= 1
        total -= 1
    } else if (choice == 3 && letterC != 0) {
        password += (0..9).random()
        letterC -= 1
        total -= 1
    } else if (letterA + letterB + letterC != 0) {
        continue
    } else {
        password += ('!'..'z').random()
        total -= 1
    }
}

for (i in 0..126) {
    if (i.toChar() + "" + i.toChar() in password) {
        password = password.toMutableList().shuffle().toString()
        print(password)
        break
    } else if (i == 126){
        print(password)
        break
    }
}
```

}

Test 9/17 states the following (for my output):

Failed test #9 of 17. Length of the password should be 100, length of your password - 11

Comment: fun main() {
    val amount = readLine()!!.toString().split(" ")
    var letterA = amount[0].toInt()
    var letterB = amount[1].toInt()
    var letterC = amount[2].toInt()
    var letterD = amount[3].toInt()
    var total = letterD
    var choice = 0
    var password = ""

Comment: Instead of putting extra information as a comment you should just edit the question and add it there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried your code?
It even prints the password. Then you will easily see that password will be

```
kotlin.Unit
```

in that case, which is 11 characters long.
Reason for that is this line:

```
password = password.toMutableList().shuffle().toString()
```

That line only gets reached when you have 2 the same characters in a row, which is probably why you didn't get it with other simpler test cases.

The reason why it's wrong is because `shuffle()` doesn't return anything, it merely shuffles the list that you call it on. Because it doesn't return anything it causes it to return `kotlin.Unit` when you apply `toString()`

How to solve it I leave up to you.

PS. just shuffling the characters in the password also doesn't guarantee it won't have any repeated characters after the shuffle.

Comment: You could suggest the alternative [shuffled](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/shuffled.html) which does return a new list

Comment: @Joffrey, true that would be an improvement but changing only that still won't be enough though. The toString of a  MutableList<Char> is not the desired outcome. And as a I mentioned, just shuffling it won't guarantee having no repeats. I could write a working solution but I rather have him try to find that himself

Comment: Right, I'm not saying `shuffled` will be enough, just saying that it might be worth mentioning its existence next to the comment "`shuffle` is wrong because it's in-place"